Faster RCNN with Pytorch Lightning
Faster RCNN model has different behaviour for model.eval() and model.train().
At model.eval()  mode model(images, targets) - returns prediction
At model.train() model model(images) return loss only
I'm using Pytorch Lightning and would like to get torchmetrics.detection.mean_ap during the training some amount  (N) of training batches.
How it can be done ?
Can I do it via val_check_interval and val_check_interval + on_validation_epoch_end, but on training batches in addition to validation set ?

By the way, the question could be more focused. The crucial part is how to calculate mAP during training at specific batch intervals using PyTorch Lightning.
To achieve this, you can create a custom callback:
class MAPCallback(pl.Callback):
    def __init__(self, every_n_batches):
        self.every_n_batches = every_n_batches
        self.map_metric = MeanAveragePrecision()

    def on_train_batch_end(self, trainer, pl_module, outputs, batch, batch_idx):
        if (batch_idx + 1) % self.every_n_batches == 0:
            # Calculate and log mAP here

Add this callback to your Trainer:
trainer = pl.Trainer(callbacks=[MAPCallback(every_n_batches=N)])

This approach allows you to calculate mAP at specified intervals during training without modifying your main training loop.
Please check it for Callback of lightning.   https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/api/lightning.pytorch.callbacks.Callback.html#lightning.pytorch.callbacks.Callback.on_train_batch_end

In your answer, how it is addressed, different FasterRCNN behaviour for model.train and model.eval ?

Also on on_train_batch_end, it will run only on every_n_batches (the last batch` or last N batches ?

You're right, I missed the mode switching. Add pl_module.eval() before predictions and pl_module.train() after in the callback. The mAP calculation occurs every N batches throughout training, not just at the end.

from where pl_module is taken ?
Please, add to the answer an example of use of the above callback.

Do you read the documentation I shared?

I would like to see a self-contained example. The link to the documentation doesn't answer the question.

Ok, one moment.

I think you can compute Mean average precision in validation_step method that is run after certain number of epoch trained in  LightningModule class
Below is a modified sample code from this article. I add validation_step in LightningModule and val_dataloader in .LightningDataModule to allow you to run MeanAveragePrecision in validation step during training batches
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import models, datasets, ops
from torchvision.transforms import v2 as transforms
from torchmetrics.detection import MeanAveragePrecision
import lightning as L

# Use a pretrained Faster R-CNN model from torchvision and modify it
class FaceDetectionModel(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = models.detection.fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn(weights="DEFAULT")
        self.map = MeanAveragePrecision(box_format="xyxy", class_metrics=True)

    def forward(self, images, targets=None):
        self.model.eval()
        output = self.model(images)
        return output 

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, annot = batch
        images, targets = FacesData.convert_inputs(imgs, annot, device=self.device)
        loss_dict = self.model(images, targets)
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        self.log('train_loss', losses)
        return losses

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        self.model.eval()
        imgs, annot = batch
        images, targets = FacesData.convert_inputs(imgs, annot, device=self.device)
        output = self.model(images)

        self.map.update(output, targets)
        map_compute = self.map.compute()
        self.log('map', map_compute['map'])
        self.model.train()

class MAPCallback(L.Callback):
    def __init__(self, every_n_batches):
        self.every_n_batches = every_n_batches
        self.map_metric = MeanAveragePrecision()

    def on_train_batch_end(self, trainer, pl_module, outputs, batch, batch_idx):
        if (batch_idx + 1) % self.every_n_batches == 0:
            pl_module.validation_step(batch, batch_idx)

class FacesData(L.LightningDataModule):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
        transforms.Resize(size=(800,), max_size=1333),
    ])

    @staticmethod
    def convert_inputs(imgs, annot, device, small_thr=0.001):
        """Conver dataset item to accepted target struture."""
        images, targets = [], []
        for img, annot in zip(imgs, annot):
            bbox = annot['bbox']
            small = (bbox[:, 2] * bbox[:, 3]) <= (img.size[1] * img.size[0] * small_thr)
            boxes = ops.box_convert(bbox[~small], in_fmt='xywh', out_fmt='xyxy')
            output_dict = FacesData.transform({"image": img, "boxes": boxes})
            images.append(output_dict['image'].to(device))
            targets.append({
                'boxes': output_dict['boxes'].to(device),
                'labels': torch.ones(len(boxes), dtype=int, device=device)
            })
        return images, targets
    
    @staticmethod
    def _collate_fn(batch):
        """Define a collate function to handle batches."""
        return tuple(zip(*batch))

    def train_dataloader(self):
        train_dataset = datasets.WIDERFace(root='./data', split='train', download=True)
        return DataLoader(
            train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=self._collate_fn
        )
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        train_dataset = datasets.WIDERFace(root='./data', split='train', download=True)
        return DataLoader(
            train_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=4, collate_fn=self._collate_fn
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = FacesData()
    model = FaceDetectionModel()
    trainer = L.Trainer(precision='16-mixed', callbacks=[MAPCallback(every_n_batches=1)])
    trainer.fit(model, data)

Edit: I made a mistake, @Ryo Matsuzaka approach of using Trainer callback was right. I borrow some code of his and add to mine as an example. It seems like you would have to switch between eval and train mode in validation step in order to make model returns MAP results while keeping the training going

Validation step by, default runs only on validation data, not training data. What change in your code make it run on Training data batches ?

@MichaelD Hmm you're right, it only runs on validation data. Update my code to use Ryo Matsuzaka 's suggestion instead

I wonder is PL has predefined callbacks for switching between model.train() and model.eval().

@MichaelD I'm not sure there is one
